# Why is Azure Cognitive Search prioritizing document content over name?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, scoring

I have set up an Azure Cognitive Search, populated an index with documents from Blob Storage, and everything seems to work fine. The documents are there, and I can search for them, but for some reason the content of the document seems to be prioritized higher than the name of the document. I want the documents that includes the search term in the name to show up first, followed by documents that contain the search term in the content.

Here is an example of the response I get after searching for a single word:
[image: Search results]

As you can see, the first hit gets a higher score than the others, even though the third hit also contains the search term in the name. I assume the second hit contains a lot of instances of the search term, but I still want name to be prioritized higher.

How can I achieve this?

Both name and content are searchable. I have tried adding a scoring profile with a weight to the name field, but doing this only seems to result in an even higher score for the first hit, and the other scores stay identical.

EDIT - Adding picture of scoring profile used for search.

In the original question, I had already added a scoring profile where metadata_storage_name was given a weight of 2. This was set to default, and removing it would drop the score of the first result to 8.3, while the others stayed identical. I have also tried "docs?search=betong&scoringProfile=FileNameBoost" this approach, although not necessary with the scoring profile set as default.
By adding content to the scoring profile as well, the other results get a boost, but this is not what I want, as the name should be prioritized above content.

[image: Scoring profile used in search]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use scoring profiles to boost documents which contain the searched term in the name.

Here's the official doc with more information around it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-scoring-profiles

Comment: I have tried adding a scoring profile. I have four documents that contains the search term in its name, however, it's only the first result that gets a boost. I even had one as default in the picture. No matter how much weight I give "metadata_storage_name", it's only the first result that varies, the other results' score stay exactly the same. I find that weird considering the word I'm searching for is clearly in the name of four of them. The documents containing the word is respectively in position 1, 3, 7 and 10 out of the 12 documents it finds.

Comment: can you update your question and add the scoring profile you created?

Comment: also, have you included the scoring profile when searching ? e.g. https://[search-service-name].search.windows.net/indexes/[index-name]/docs?search=betong&scoringProfile=FileNameBoost

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have now updated the question with extra information regarding the scoring profile used.